# How to move using precision at a random angle?

Tags: transforms

In my screenshot I rotate the whole object in edit mode (any random angle so the axis won't line up with the grid). I want to add a segment or edge (blue line in the screeshot). I can do this with subdivide, but how to precisely make it exactly 1 unit from the red edge? What is the fastest workflow? is there anyway in Blender I can hava a custom construction plane?

[image]
[image]

Comment: you just rotated your object. In Local Space your Object is still aligned and you can still just move it along the (I guess) Y axis for a distance of 1. Is that what you want? I will make an answer from it if it is

Comment: In your example everything is  at right angles. If not ( a triangle for instance) do you want blue edge to be parallel with red, or with ends  1 unit  from corners along edges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select a face, turn the transform orientation to "normal", then click the plus button: this will create a new set of trasform orientation that you can use to manipulate your vertices, edges and faces along the three normal vectors of the first face you selected.

[image]

Then in the overlays section you can activate the measurement function, to get infos of edges lenghts and faces areas.

[image]